# C++ STL priority_queue , the way to compare objects

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I have no idea how to implement priority_queue, when comparing an objects integer field , it's is clear.
For example

```
bool operator()(const Toast &t1, const Toast &t2) const
{
    int t1value = t1.bread * 1000 + t1.butter;
    int t2value = t2.bread * 1000 + t2.butter;
    return t1value < t2value;
}
```

This will place the objects in the heap according to the values. 
The question is how   to compare objects according to the bool fields? How to store several objects according to the boolean type?
For example :
vip=**true**, notvip=**false**;
Vip1 , notVip2, Vip3.
The result should be: Vip1,Vip3,notVip2;
Can you give me an idea.

Comment: I recommend you read e.g. [this `std::priority_queue` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), it contains a link to an exact definition of what's required of the comparison function.

Comment: Do you have two attributes that represent the exact opposite of each other? If so, reduce that to one attribute first. Then, use std::less<bool> to compare the attribute, i.e. delegate the comparison of the containing object to a comparison of the according field within.

Comment: Please clarify your question. This vip stiff doesn't make any sense.

Comment: ok if i do this  if(c1.status == true && c2.status== false ) return c1.status>c2.status; , i will get an error it will not store my objects; i need to store true first then to store false;

Comment: Again, your question makes no sense whatsoever. What is "store"? What does that mean?  What is "c1", what is "c2"? The sample code you posted doesn't have anything called "c1" or "c2". Every time you try to explain your question, you throw out something new, that has not been mentioned before. The trick to getting the right answer from someone is to explain yourself properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. I'm going to assume that the structure that you want to sort is `Toast`.

If you simply want to prioritize `Toast`s based on a `bool`, say `status`, your comparison object is pretty easy:

```
class mycomparison
{
public:
    bool operator() (const Toast& lhs, const Toast& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.status < rhs.status;
    }
};
```

Now I'm going to assume the following to expand on this, given `Toast` has the following `bool` members listed in order of most significant to least significant: `vip`, `notvip`, Vip1`,`Vip3`, and`notVip2`, I'm also assuming that the comparison on "not" members should be inverted:

```
class mycomparison
{
public:
    bool operator() (const Toast& lhs, const Toast& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.vip < rhs.vip || lhs.vip == rhs.vip && // return true if rhs.vip is the only true or continue to test
             ( lhs.noVip > rhs.noVip || lhs.noVip == rhs.noVip && // return true if rhs.noVip is the only false or continue to test
             ( lhs.Vip1 < rhs.Vip1 || lhs.Vip1 == rhs.Vip1 && // return true if lhs.Vip1 is less than rhs.Vip1 or continue to test
             ( lhs.Vip3 < rhs.Vip3 || lhs.Vip3 == rhs.Vip3 && // return true if lhs.Vip3 is less than rhs.Vip3 or continue to test
               lhs.notVip2 > rhs.notVip2 ) ) ); // return true if lhs.notVip2 is greater than rhs.notVip2 or return false
    }
};
```

Note that either of these `mycomparison` classes works fine if the members are `bool`s or any other type for which `operator<`, `operator>` and `operator==` is defined. To use `mycomparision` in a `std::priority_queue` you'll just need to pass it as the comparison object in `std::priority_queue`'s ctor, for example: `std::priority_queue< Toast > foo( mycomparison() );`